# Rails ajax respond_to js error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I was following this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy), but I encountered some troubles.
I got an controller method called `sort_new_section`, and in the `erb`, it would use `ajax` to trigger this controller. Then response to its `js.erb` and render a partial view.

In **create_question_controller**

```
def sort_new_seciton 
...
    @sort_volume = volume
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js   
    end
end
```

In **view/create_question/sort_new_section.js.erb**

```
$('#xxx').append("<%= j render :partial => 'create_question/section_in_panel', :locals => {:volume_id => @sort_volume, } %>");
```

However, it threw this error.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_create_question/sort_new_seciton, create_question/sort_new_seciton, application/sort_new_seciton with {:locale=>[:"zh-TW", :en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

Comment: Dud you try without `respond_to` section?

Comment: And check your view path. It should `views/path/to` not `view/...` as you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says `sort_new_seciton`, not `sort_new_section`.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_create_question/sort_new_seciton, create_question/sort_new_seciton, application/sort_new_seciton with {:locale=>[:"zh-TW", :en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

Looks like you have a typo in your code. Specifically, look at your controller method. It's `sort_new_seciton`.

Comment: Thanks! It's my fault.